# Once, when his wife had been alive, he had had a fine house

Tags: past-perfect, discourse-context

so kind of confusing sentence

Once, when his wife had been alive, he had had a fine house.

so here past perfect is used twice. and i'm not sure if it's possible to use one twice, at least not by the grammar. and i'm not sure which was first here. may be both were at the same time in the past.

or the sentence is not written grammatically. can you explain?

thaks

Comment: The past perfect sounds rather ridiculous. One could simply say, *When his wife was alive he had a fine house.*

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way: suppose you're telling the story of a homeless man.

> His wife died in 2004. Before that, when his wife **had been**<sup>PAST PERFECT</sup> alive, he **had had**<sup>PAST PERFECT</sup> someone to live for; but now he **gave**<sup>SIMPLE PAST</sup> up on life. Before that, when he **had wanted**<sup>PAST PERFECT</sup> to give her a perfect home, he **had had**<sup>PAST PERFECT</sup> a high-paying job and a fine house; but now he **stopped**<sup>SIMPLE PAST</sup> going to work, he **lost**<sup>SIMPLE PAST</sup> his job, he **could**<sup>SIMPLE PAST</sup> no longer make the mortgage payments and the bank **foreclosed**<sup>SIMPLE PAST</sup> on his mortgage.

The past perfect occurs only in a past context. Your story starts with her death, and goes on from there; it mentions events ***before*** that context, because they in some sense give rise to the situation which obtained at that time, and contrast with your story of what happened afterward.